# RMarkdown Word Output: Issue with Changing Page Orientation

Tags: r, templates, ms-word, r-markdown

I've encountered an issue while working with RMarkdown to generate Word documents, specifically when changing the page orientation from portrait to landscape. Here's the problem:

I'm using RMarkdown to write my undergraduate thesis in Word format. Initially, everything worked perfectly in portrait mode. However, when I tried switching to landscape mode, I encountered an issue. The text and image specified in the "heading" of the Word template stopped appearing.

I attempted to change the page orientation and re-render, but the problem persisted. I also investigated the resulting documents and realized that I might need to adjust various "headings." I made those adjustments, but it still didn't resolve the issue.

I've created a GitHub repository with reproducible examples:

https://github.com/amilcar-pg/ajuste_heading

In the "exemplo_funcional" folder, rendering the index.Rmd file works as expected (all pages in the same orientation).

In the "exemplo_nao_funcional_mesmo_template" folder, I changed only the "03-uma_tabela.Rmd" file to landscape format, resulting in the heading disappearing.

In the "exemplo_nao_funcional_template_ajustado" folder, I made adjustments to not only the "03-uma_tabela.Rmd" file but also the "template.docx," including pages in both landscape and portrait formats to generate different headings, but the issue persists.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I tried modifying the "heading" on the word template file, but it did not work.